# Rails custom join by combining fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have 2 models, `PotentialClient` and `Client`.  `PotentialClient` and `Client` have a non-unique field `:mindbody_id`, and `Client` also has a unique field, `:unique_mb`, that is equal to `"#{location_id}{mindbody_id}"`, making the field unique.  `:location_id` is also present on `PotentialClient`, but `:unique_mb` is not.

Is there a way to join `PotentialClient` and `Client` through `:unique_mb` since it's present on `Client` and `PotentialClient` has all the information necessary to generate the field?

Comment: Are you sure `{location_id}{mindbody_id}` is going to be unique? What if you had location 11 and mindbody 2, and then location 1 and mindbody 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain your `:unique_mb` field is not guaranteed to be unique. You'd be better off just joining them on two separate fields rather than trying to manufacture your own unique combination of the two.

Since you haven't given an example of how you intend to use this, I'm going to assume that when you say you want to join them you're actually just looking for matching `PotentialClient` records for a given `Client`?

In that case, you could just do something like this:

```rb
@client = Client.find(params[:id]) # or however you're finding your Client record
@potential_clients = PotentialClient.where(location: @client.location, mindbody: @client.mindbody)
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, it would be useful for you to provide a more detailed example of what you're trying to achieve, show the code you've tried so far and any errors you've received.